# Can you join three tables on the same key if that key could be missing from one or more of the tables?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I'm taking three tables and joining them all together using the same primary key, but with no guarantee that all values exist across all three tables, and I want every value to end up in the final join.

For example, there's a `TableA`, `TableB`, and `TableC`, each with only one column (we'll just call the columns `colA`, `colB`, and `colC`). Value `10` is present in `TableA` and `TableC`, but not `TableB`.

```
SELECT * FROM TableA FULL OUTER JOIN TableB ON TableA.colA = TableB.colB 
                     FULL OUTER JOIN TableC ON TableB.colB = TableC.colC;

+--------+  +--------+  +--------+
|  colA  |  |  colB  |  |  colC  |
+--------+  +--------+  +--------+
|      5 |  |      5 |  |      5 |
|     10 |  |     15 |  |     10 |
|     15 |  +--------+  |     15 |
+--------+              +--------+
```

In the above example, I end up with something like this after the joins:

```
+--------+--------+--------+
|  colA  |  colB  |  colC  |
+--------+--------+--------+
| 5      | 5      | 5      |
| null   | null   | 10     |
| 15     | 15     | 15     |
| 10     | null   | null   |
+--------+--------+--------+
```

My expected result is this:

```
+--------+--------+--------+
|  colA  |  colB  |  colC  |
+--------+--------+--------+
|      5 | 5      |      5 |
|     10 | null   |     10 |
|     15 | 15     |     15 |
+--------+--------+--------+
```

The logic for my join is to first join `TableA` and `TableB`, then join the result with `TableC`. In this specific scenario, the join does not work. The join can try to match on the column passed through from `TableA` or the column from `TableB`, but I'm not sure how to make it check both.

Because I first joined `TableA` and `TableB`, there was no matching value in `TableB`. When I try to join `TableC` on `TableB`, it also finds no match, even though the key exists in `TableA`.

The closest I've gotten to my desired result is by using this query:

```
SELECT * FROM TableA FULL OUTER JOIN TableB ON TableA.colA = TableB.colB 
                     RIGHT OUTER JOIN TableC ON TableC.colC IN (TableA.colA, TableB.colB);

+------+  +------+  +------+     +------+------+------+
| colA |  | colB |  | colC |     | colA | colB | colC |
+------+  +------+  +------+     +------+------+------+
|    5 |  |    5 |  |    5 |     | 5    | 5    |    5 |
|   10 |  |   15 |  |   10 | --> | 10   | null |   10 |
|   15 |  |   25 |  |   15 |     | 15   | 15   |   15 |
+------+  +------+  |   20 |     | null | null |   20 |
                    +------+     +------+------+------+
```

Expected result:

```
+------+------+------+
| colA | colB | colC |
+------+------+------+
| 5    | 5    | 5    |
| 10   | null | 10   |
| 15   | 15   | 15   |
| null | null | 20   |
| null | 25   | null |
+------+------+------+
```

This, unfortunately, does not include values that **only** exist in `TableA` or `TableB` in the final joined table, which is why I was using the `FULL OUTER JOIN` in the first place. With the `FULL OUTER JOIN`, I can't use the `IN` clause. Is there a solution that gives me what I want?

DB Fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/faMLh4EAAKfBotXbaDofaQ/1

Comment: You don't actually clearly explain what you want. You describe some aspects of what you want. What is your example (why "something like" & not exactly like?) an example of? When giving a business relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values.

Comment: Learn what OUTER JOINs return: LEFT/RIGHT JOIN ON return INNER JOIN ON rows UNION ALL unmatched left/right table rows extended by NULLs. FULL JOIN ON returns INNER JOIN ON rows UNION ALL unmatched left & right table rows extended by NULLs. Always know what INNER JOIN you want as part of an OUTER JOIN.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a version that demonstrates a fully three way full outer join.  A successful query will return seven rows:

```
+------+  +------+  +------+     +------+------+------+
| colA |  | colB |  | colC |     | colA | colB | colC |
+------+  +------+  +------+     +------+------+------+
|    1 |  |    2 |  |    4 |     |    1 | null | null |
|    3 |  |    3 |  |    5 | --> | null |    2 | null |
|    5 |  |    6 |  |    6 |     |    3 |    3 | null |
|    7 |  |    7 |  |    7 |     | null | null |    4 |
+------+  +------+  +------+     |    5 | null |    5 |
                                 | null |    6 |    6 |
                                 |    7 |    7 |    7 |
                                 +------+------+------+
```

```
select ColA, ColB, ColC
  from TableA
  full join TableB
    on ColA=ColB
  full join TableC
    on ColC=coalesce(ColA, ColB)
order by coalesce(ColA, ColB, ColC);
```

The secret is to `coalesce` the prior table keys in the join condition of each additional table.

You can see it in action [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/605d0/4)

Answer (score 0):

This join combination will give you your desired results:

```
select * 
from (SELECT * 
      FROM TableC
      full outer join TableB on TableC.colC = TableB.colB ) t1
left join TableA on t1.colc = TableA.colA or  t1.colB = TableA.colA
```

[Here is a demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/faMLh4EAAKfBotXbaDofaQ/2)

It was a different join you needed. Here is another example:

```
select * from 
(SELECT * 
FROM TableC
full outer join TableB on TableC.colC = TableB.colB ) t1
full join TableA on t1.colc = TableA.colA
```

[Here is a demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/faMLh4EAAKfBotXbaDofaQ/6)

Comment: I can break this by including a value in `TableA` that is not in either `TableB` or `TableC`: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/faMLh4EAAKfBotXbaDofaQ/3 Is it possible to create such a query that won't drop values from `TableA` in this case?

Comment: Hi @user-2147482428 I have added another query you can check. Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

I think you want `left join`s:

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA LEFT OUTER JOIN
     TableB
     ON TableA.colA = TableB.colB LEFT JOIN
     TableC
     ON TableA.colA = TableC.colC;
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8VCiaT1SUstDLRsS3uQX61/0).

Comment: That does not give the expected result, and that is a link to my original fiddle.

Comment: @user-2147482428 . . . I consider that a bug in that fiddle environment.  It requires clicking on "fork" (an obvious name, sigh) to  get a new link.  I added a link showing the code working.